# Find the inverse of a specific Vandermonde matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $$ 
V=\begin{bmatrix}
      1&          1&          1&     \cdots&        1  \\ 
  1&      \xi&       \xi^{2}&     \cdots&    \xi^{n-1}     \\ 
  1&       \xi^{2}&      \xi^{4}&     \cdots&    \xi^{2(n-1)}     \\ 
 \vdots&     \vdots&     \vdots&     \ddots&   \vdots     \\
  1&   \xi^{n-1}&    \xi^{2(n-1)}&     \cdots&   \xi^{(n-1)(n-1)}     
\end{bmatrix}$$
Where $\xi =\cos\frac{2\pi}{n}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{n}$.

Show the  inverse  matrix of $V$.

---

We  know  that $V$ is a  Vandermonde matrix,maybe I can use  [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Vandermonde's_Matrix) to get $V^{-1}$.But $V$ is a  specific Vandermonde matrix, there should  have another ways to find the $V^{-1}$.If you have some  good ideas,please give me some hints. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure $\xi$ is written in the right way? I bet that some $n$ is missing. Otherwise, $\xi=i$.

Comment: I hope I got it right that $\xi$ was meant to be separate from the matrix. Let me know if I did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint - assuming $\xi=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$:** I strongly suggest you to multiply $V$ by $V^{H}$ to check that: 
$$ V\cdot V^H = n\, I.$$
That is the orthogonality property of the discrete Fourier transform.